# How to send a local notification and repeat at set time intervals OSX

Tags: javascript, php, html, osx-mavericks

How would I approach sending a local notification with a repeated notification at set intervals?

```
 setInterval(function() {
    notification.show();
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: what you mean with that? in javascript? objective-c? and php cant send notifications to the computer

Comment: You can try it on chrome & safari, http://www.go4expert.com/articles/send-desktop-notifications-chrome-t30017/

Comment: Correct, In javascript.